# b-button v-on:click won't execute function

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a b-card

```
<b-card  v-for="todolist in todolists" style='max-width: 20rem;' class='mb-2'>
    <b-card-title>{{todolist[1].title}}</b-card-title>

    <b-button href='#' variant='primary' v-on:click.native="changeSelected">View</b-button>
</b-card>
```

It loops through an array containing todo lists and creates a card for each one (when clicking on the button i want the todo list to appear).

The on:click of the button doesn't execute the function that it is linked to and i can't work out why

This is inside my `export default`, as well as some other stuff that isn't really related to the issue.

```
exports default {
    data () {
        return {
          id: this.$route.params.id,
          section: {},
          todolists: [],
          selected: false,
          user: ''
        }
      },
      methods: {
        changeSelected () {
          this.selected = true
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but I wouldn't expect a `.native` event to ever fire on a component. If the component emits a Vue event, that's what you should listen for.

Comment: Ok so i initially tried it without `.native` and now when i remove it it works. Sod's law i guess ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ @StephenThomas

Comment: You should write up the solution. It could help the next person

Answer (score 1):

Removing `.native` from the `v-on:click` made it work.

Answer (score 1):

It might be long time, but updated event handler is changed from `v-on:click="changeSelected"` to `@click="changeSelected"`

Comment: Those do the same thing. `@` is a shorthand of `v-on:`